# How to use multi client supported ADO.Net parameter

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2008, ado.net

I am building a ado.net wrapper that can connect with any database(supported by ADO.Net)basically from SQl, Oledb,Odbc,Oracle,Sqlite etc. I implemented the connection and all other basic things. But at a point where my queries need parameter to pass from other levels , i am stucked there. I know for that purpose we use IDataParameterCollection or IDbDataParameters etc. But do not know the way to implement.

So you guys are requested to please help me out. It would be a great help.

OR

You can say in short, i need an independent way of passing parameters that will be used in all type of clients, whether it is SqlClient, OracleClient or any other client.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Is there nobody who has got my answer or my question is vague. I have'nt seen SO members so slow... Please any comments or any feedback , i am eagerly waiting for solution... please provide some solution......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. On the user side :

```
SqlParameter s1 = new SqlParameter();
s1.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
s1.ParameterName = "s1";

SqlParameter s2 = new SqlParameter();
s2.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
s2.ParameterName = "s2";

this.ExecuteScalar("query", new IDataParameter[] { s1, s2 });
```

And on the other side :

```
public int ExecuteScalar(string commandText, IDataParameter[] param)
      {
         IDbCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
         cmd.CommandText = commandText;
         foreach (IDataParameter p in param)
            cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

(cmd is the DbCommand instance)

```
DbParameter p = cmd.CreateParameter();
p.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
p.Value = the_value;
p.ParameterName = the_param_name;
p.DbType = ...

cmd.Parameters.Add(p);
```

Then, queries are like `select * from table where field = ?`. But, be careful with the order or creating parameters.

The `?` joker should be independent.

Comment: Ok, so just replace DbParameter by IDbDataParameter. It should also work ;)

Comment: Few queries
1. I am using IDbCommand instead of DbCommand. 
2. My methods signature are public int ExecuteScalar(string commandText, IDataParameter[] params).
3. I want users to pass parameters only from their data layer. Something like this 
var arr = new [] { new sqlparam(),new sqlparam(),new sqlparam(),new sqlparam(),} any way to pass this var arr as idataparameter